# Ubuntu 14 Server - Setting up a username password prompt before downloading a file

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04

I have an Ubuntu 14 server set up (I am using a LAMP Stack) and it is currently hosting a website I made. I have uploaded a zip file there and anyone with the link can go a head and download it. However, this can get problematic really fast. Let's say that the files can go to a path like:

```
homepage.com/src/file1.zip
```

Anyone with enough curiosity can go ahead and type in `homepage.com/src/` and see the entire directory and begin to download the other files they may see there. It also doesn't stop them from trying to access other folders like `homepage.com/source/` and just try and fish out folders.

To prevent this, my idea is to create an "AuthFile" for my folder/file so that when anyone stumbles upon it, they have to input the correct username password to be able to download it. It would be similar to [securing the phpMyAdmin Page as shown in this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04), and would result in this prompt:

[image: auth screen]

However, upon going over creating AuthFiles, I don't think I can apply this to a folder or a file. Hence, bringing me to my main question:

How can I prompt the user to input a username password combination before being able to download a file?

If that isn't an option, how do you guys manage controlling who gets to download certain files on a server an making sure that no one just manages to walk up on your files?

Any help and guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: which web server are you using?

Comment: @mzhaase err I am not sure if I'm answering your question but I am using DigitalOcean to host the website and I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

Comment: you must be running some webserver software to have data accessible over the network, which one is it? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: I am running Apache. I should edit that in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a .htaccess in apache.

See the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) for details.

Basically, .htaccess allows to change the configuration of Apache on a folder level. You just place a file named .htaccess in the folder, and edit it. For basic authentication you first need to create a credential file:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd username
```

Then you can place a file named .htaccess in the folder you want to protect, with the following contents:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

The path for the .htpasswd can be chosen freely, but take care to put it into a folder that is not accessible by the public.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. I create an htpasswrd with a different username. I then added an htaccess file in the folder I wanted to secure using `sudo nano /file/directory/.htaccess` then I pasted the contents in. I refreshed my folder and nothing happens, I can still download the file without being prompted a password. Do I need to restart apache?

Comment: is the .htaccess readable for the apache user?

Comment: I can go and execute `sudo nano .htaccess` (given I'm in the folder) and I can view the file just right.

Comment: I had to reset the apache server :D